# How do I attach a .jpeg, or PDF file to my email in python?

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I have written a program which sends emails with python, it works for sending standard emails but I am having trouble attaching a file to it. I have watched several videos, and read a bunch of posts on this, but everything that I can find seems to be outdated and so doesn't work.
Here is what I have so far:

```
import os
from email.message import EmailMessage
import ssl
import smtplib
email_sender = 'Example@gmail.com'
Password = 'gmail app password'
email_receiver = 'Example@gmail.com'
subject = 'message subject'
body = 'message body text'
em = EmailMessage()
em['From'] = email_sender
em['To'] = email_receiver
em['Subject'] = subject
em.set_content(body)
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
        smtp.login(email_sender, Password)
        smtp.sendmail(email_sender, email_receiver, em.as_string())
```

Thank you for any help that you can give, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you need [.add_attachment()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html):

```
em.add_attachment(<the file to attach>, subtype=".pdf", filename="spam.pdf")
```